# htaccess постраничная навигация

Tags: php, .htaccess

есть фактический файл view_catalog.php (переименовывается просто в "catalog") который при определенном условии может являться: каталогом, выводить категории, выводить типы товаров. У меня не получается сделать, чтоб работала постраничная навигация при отображении "Типа товара". Количество страниц и товаров формирует правильно, но при нажатии на любую страницу в адресной строке номер страницы меняется mysite.com/catalog/category/typetovar?page=2 и.т.д
но товар не меняется, всегда отображаются товары первой страницы.

все вот это работает
RewriteRule ^catalog$ view_catalog.php [L]

RewriteRule ^catalog/([a-z0-9-]+)?$ view_catalog.php?typecategory=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^catalog/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)?$ view_catalog.php?typecategory=$1&typetovar=$2 [L]

а этот вариант при потытке добавить номер страницы не работает

RewriteRule ^catalog/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ view_catalog.php?typecategory=$1&typetovar=$2&page=$3 [L]

Если кто шарит в этом, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: единая точка входа в приложение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идем на сайт `https://regex101.com/` вбиваем каждую регулярку по-очереди (не забываем экранировать "/"). В поле ниже вбиваем тестируемые URL и смотрим результаты:

```
RewriteRule ^catalog$ view_catalog.php [L]
```

Как видим под регулярное выражение `^catalog$` подойдет только один вариант `URL` - `mycite.com/catalog` и при переходе по нему будет вызван `view_catalog.php`

Тут все верно.

Смотрим следующее правило

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)?$ view_catalog.php?typecategory=$1&typetovar=$2 [L]
```

Что же у нас может подойти под регулярное выражение `catalog/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)?`...

Все, что начинается на `catalog`, и после первого и второго слэша содержит латинские `a...z` (только в нижнем регистре, кстати почему?) + цифры + символ `-` и все это любой длины ( на что намекает символ `+`) будет перенаправлено на тот же `view_catalog.php`, но при этом содержимое после первого слэша будет передано в него как GET-параметр `typecategory`, а содержимое после второго как GET-параметр `typetovar`.

Тут тоже все верно.

Смотрим последнее правило.

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ view_catalog.php?typecategory=$1&typetovar=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

Попытаемся понять, какой `URL` сможет подойти под регулярное выражение `catalog/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+`.

Практически такой же, что и в предыдущем правиле с добавлением в URL-е под-URL `/page/` после которого должен идти номер страницы `([0-9]+)` любой длины (помните `+` ?) и URL может заканчиваться на `/`, но не обязательно ( спасибо за это символу `?` в конце), а вот `+` после `(/?)` явно лишний, он говорит о том, что `/` в конце может идти сколько угодно т.е а-ля `/////`

Теперь, поняв как работает регулярное выражение ищущее совпадение в `URL`, смотрим по какому же `URL` приходите Вы - `mysite.com/catalog/category/typetovar?page=2`
и видим, что Вы передали `page` не как под-URL, а как GET-параметр.

Поняв это исправляемся и начинаем либо ходить по правильному `URL` - `mysite.com/catalog/category/typetovar/page/2`, либо меняем регулярное выражение на
подходящее под `URL`

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)(/?)?page=([0-9]+)$ view_catalog.php?typecategory=$1&typetovar=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой развернутый и подробный ответ, но это тоже не работает. Я не знаю почему но работает вот этот код. Дошел до него случайно и логику работы тоже не пойму   RewriteRule ^catalog$ view_catalog.php [L]   
RewriteRule ^catalog/([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ view_catalog.php?typecategory=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ view_catalog.php?typecategory=$1&typetovar=$2 [NC,L,QSA] причем именно с этими флагами [NC,L,QSA]

Comment: @billov если то, что описано в ответе не работает, то его **нельзя отмечать галочкой**. Галочка предназначена для того, чтобы отмечать действительно правильный **и рабочий** ответ, а не для того, чтобы "отблагодарить отвечающего"